# Is supremum part of the set or it is the bigest element out of it?

Tags: analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

> "If $\sup A$ is in $A$, then is $\sup A$  called also Maximum: $\max A$."

So that means that $\sup A$ can be outside the set $A$?
And lastly the upper barrier(or bound, not sure) is from $A$, right?

Comment: Yes, the supremum can be outside of the set.  Take for example the set $\{1-\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.  The supremum in this case would be 1, however notice that 1 is not in fact in the set as there is no natural number $n$ for which $1 = 1-\frac{1}{n}$.  It can be thought of as the smallest upper bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have sets that don't contain their supremum. A simple example is the set $(0,1)$: the supremum of this set is 1 since 1 is greater than or equal to any element of this set, but it is also the lowest possible upper bound. Clearly 1 is not in the set either.

To your second question, if I'm reading it right, one can similarly say that an upper bound is not necessarily in the set, and you can even say it won't be in the set if it is not the supremum..

Comment: Your last statement seems incorrect to me, according to the following proof: Say x is an upper bound to S. Say x is in S. Then there does not exist an upper bound less than x, because anything less than x is less than an element in S, and hence not an upper bound. Since x is the least upper bound, it is supremum. In other words (x upper bound to S) AND (x in S) implies (x = sup S). The contrapositive of this is: (x not supremum) implies (x not upper bound to S) OR (x not in S). If x is assumed to be an upper bound, we have: (x upper bound) AND (x not supremum) implies (x not in S).

Comment: This last statement, (x upper bound) AND (x not supremum) implies (x not in S) contradicts your final claim, that (x upper bound) AND (x not supremum) does not imply (x not in S).

In otherwords, an upper bound not being supremum absolutely *does* imply it is not in the set. Or am I misunderstanding something? Can someone confirm me on this?

Comment: My wording does seem vague, but I did say exactly what you claim is true:  "it (the upper bound) won't (cannot) be in the set if it is not the supremum."

Comment: Oh dear! I am very sorry. As it happens, I actually misread your statement (several times in a row, in fact) as "and you *can't* even say it won't be in the set if it is not the supremum." Thank you for replying to my comment to confirm that we agree! I am learning this stuff, so it helps to attempt proofs like this. Upvote to you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that what it means. For example, $\sup (0,1)=1\notin (0,1)$. And since $\sup A$ is the *least* upper bound, if $\sup A\notin A$ it means that there is no element of $A$ which is an upper bound of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum would note that the supremum can be outside the set as various examples demonstrate:

> sup { x ∈ ℚ: $x^2$ < 2 } = $\sqrt2$

The upper bound may or may not be part of the set. In the example above, the bound isn't part of the set.